# How to add a new tag into a XML file using sed command?

Tags: shell, sed

I have tried the command

```
sed -i.bak '/->/ r Dummy.txt' manifest.xml
```

and was successful. I just want to add the text directly into xml instead of reading the string from temporary text file. I am not a regular user of shell commands. I am running this script on Mac OS, if that's relevant.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand the question. Your script was successful and looks to do a sensible thing. Could you elaborate on the problem, possibly with an example?

Comment: something like `sed -i.bak '/->/ i myTextwithoutXMLmarkupChars' manifest.xml` which may "insert" the string myTextwithoutXMLmarkupChars into your file before it finds any `->` . You may want to sub `a` (append (after)) for `i`. The implementation of `i` and `a` varies widely, so may or maynot work. At least is it something to search for more specifically. Good luck.

Comment: @ymbirtt Currently I am fetching the string from a temporary text file and appending it into the xml file. It would be great if I am able to add the string directly from the command into the xml file.

Comment: Ah, so `Dummy.txt` should refer to the content of `Dummy.txt`, and not to the literal string `"Dummy.txt"`?

Comment: Yes that's correct. The temp. text file has a tag that I need to insert into xml file after the pattern is found.